Counting start and end states with a pivot table in R
I have a table of data with studentIDs,TestingWindow, and BenchmarkCategories. Values for TestingWindow are "Start of Year" or "End of Year." Values for the TestingData are Urgent Intervention, Intervention, On Watch, At Benchmark, Above Benchmark.
Here's some sample data. Notice student 123 is missing a result of End of Year.



studentIDs
ScreeningPeriodWindowName <chr>
DistrictBenchmarkCategoryName <chr>




123
StartofYear
Urgent Intervention


456
StartofYear
Intervention


456
EndofYear
At Benchmark


789
StartofYear
On Watch


789
EndofYear
Above Benchmark



I want to display the movement of students between BenchmarkCategories between the start and end of year. I'd like a table to show this. The key is to show changes for individual students, rather than total counts. "How many students moved from Urgent Intervention to On Watch?"
Here's what the table should look like, with Column A the start of year categories and Row 1 the End of Year Categories. (middle cells blank but I think you see the pattern)



v start    end>
Urgent Intervention
Intervention
On Watch
At Benchmark
Above Benchmark




Urgent Intervention
count of Urgent to Urgent
count of Urgent  to Intervention
count of Urgent to On Watch
Count of Urgent to At Benchmark
count of Urgent to Above Benchmark


Intervention







On Watch







At Benchmark







Above Benchmark
count of Above to Urgent
count of Above to Intervention
count of Above to On Watch
count of Above to At Benchmark
count of Above to Above



In Excel pivot tables this is trivial (defining rows and columns, count IDs) but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it in terms of grouping and summarizing (or pivot-tabling) in R. Thanks.
I have tried pivot_wider and pivot_longer, but each only gets me the row or column headings and one set of counts.
progress <- reading_data %>%
  select(studentID,TestingWindow,BenchmarkCategories) %>%
  group_by(TestingWindow,BenchmarkCategories) %>%
  summarize(count=n_distinct(studentID)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=TestingWindow,values_from=count)

progress


You can do this using two pivot_wider() calls:

first pivot_wider() to create separate columns for each value in TestingWindow e.g. StartofYear and EndofYear
create counts per StartofYear/EndofYear pairing, then pivot_wider() again so EndofYear values are pivoted to columns

Note that if you want all BenchmarkCategories to be included in the result, you'll need an extra step as detailed below. I have also included a larger example dataset to illustrate results.
First, with your sample data (with modified column names to match your code pipe column names):
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

reading_data <- structure(list(studentID = c(123L, 456L, 456L, 789L, 789L), TestingWindow = c("StartofYear", 
"StartofYear", "EndofYear", "StartofYear", "EndofYear"), BenchmarkCategories = c("Urgent Intervention", 
"Intervention", "At Benchmark", "On Watch", "Above Benchmark"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

progress <- reading_data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = TestingWindow,
              values_from = BenchmarkCategories) |>
  count(StartofYear, EndofYear, .drop = FALSE) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = EndofYear,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0) |>
  rename(`v start end >` = StartofYear)

progress
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   `v start end >`     `At Benchmark` `Above Benchmark`  `NA`
#   <chr>                        <int>             <int> <int>
# 1 Intervention                     1                 0     0
# 2 On Watch                         0                 1     0
# 3 Urgent Intervention              0                 0     1

Pairs not represented are dropped so not all BenchmarkCategories are present. Also, the NA column counts the incomplete records e.g. studentID == 123.
If you want all BenchmarkCategories in the result:
# Create vector of all unique BenchmarkCategories
bmc <- unique(reading_data$BenchmarkCategories)

progress <- reading_data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = TestingWindow,
              values_from = BenchmarkCategories) |>
  count(StartofYear, EndofYear, .drop = FALSE) |>
  complete(StartofYear = bmc,
           EndofYear = bmc,
           fill = list(n = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = EndofYear,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0) |>
  rename(`v start end >` = StartofYear)
  

progress
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   StartofYear         `Above Benchmark` `At Benchmark` Intervention `On Watch` `Urgent Intervention`  `NA`
#   <chr>                           <int>          <int>        <int>      <int>                 <int> <int>
# 1 Above Benchmark                     0              0            0          0                     0     0
# 2 At Benchmark                        0              0            0          0                     0     0
# 3 Intervention                        0              1            0          0                     0     0
# 4 On Watch                            1              0            0          0                     0     0
# 5 Urgent Intervention                 0              0            0          0                     0     1

Example using larger example dataset:
set.seed(42)
reading_data <- data.frame(
  studentID = c(123, rep(456:789, each = 2)),
  TestingWindow = c("StartofYear", rep(c("StartofYear", "EndofYear"), 334)),
  BenchmarkCategories = sample(c("Urgent Intervention","Intervention",
                                 "At Benchmark", "On Watch", "Above Benchmark"),
                               669, replace = TRUE))

progress <- reading_data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = TestingWindow,
              values_from = BenchmarkCategories) |>
  count(StartofYear, EndofYear, .drop = FALSE) |>
  # complete(StartofYear = bmc,
  #          EndofYear = bmc,
  #          fill = list(n = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = EndofYear,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0) |>
  rename(`v start end >` = StartofYear)

progress
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   `v start end >`     `Above Benchmark` `At Benchmark` Intervention `On Watch` `Urgent Intervention`  `NA`
#   <chr>                           <int>          <int>        <int>      <int>                 <int> <int>
# 1 Above Benchmark                    12              8           13         13                     8     0
# 2 At Benchmark                       14              9           11         12                    15     0
# 3 Intervention                       18             17           18         15                    20     0
# 4 On Watch                           14             10           14          7                    15     0
# 5 Urgent Intervention                11             21           14         17                     8     1


You can pivot first, and then simply use the table function:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

reading_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = TestingWindow, values_from=BenchmarkCategories) %>%
  select(-studentID) %>%
  table(useNA="ifany")


                     EndofYear
StartofYear           Above Benchmark At Benchmark <NA>
  Intervention                      0            1    0
  On Watch                          1            0    0
  Urgent Intervention               0            0    1


Data:
reading_data <- structure(list(studentID = c(123L, 456L, 456L, 789L, 789L), TestingWindow = c("StartofYear", 
"StartofYear", "EndofYear", "StartofYear", "EndofYear"), BenchmarkCategories = c("Urgent Intervention", 
"Intervention", "At Benchmark", "On Watch", "Above Benchmark"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


This produced the result of multiple tables, one for each of the starting benchmarks. Thank you for your response!

This is not particularly elegant but here is one way using reshape2::dcast and plyr::rbind.fill.matrix. I expect there is a cleaner way.
This uses each unique value of df$bench and filters for df2$start for that value, makes a table of the filtered data's end value, transforms the table to a matrix and binds those together for each value of bench in the original data.
df <- data.frame(
  ids = c(123, 456, 456, 789, 789),
  time = c("start", "start", "end", "start", "end"),
  bench = c("urgent", "intervene", "benchmark", "watch", "above")
)

df2 <- reshape2::dcast(df, ids ~ time, value.var = "bench")
tab <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix, lapply(unique(df$bench), function(i) {
  sub <- df2[df2$start == i, ]
  if (nrow(sub) > 0 & any(!is.na(sub$end))) {
    tab <- table(sub$start, sub$end)
    matrix(tab, ncol = ncol(tab), dimnames = dimnames(tab))
  } else {
    out <- matrix(0)
    colnames(out) <- i
    out
  }
}))
rownames(tab) <- unique(df$bench)
tab

          urgent benchmark above
urgent         0        NA    NA
intervene     NA         1    NA
benchmark     NA         0    NA
watch         NA        NA     1
above         NA        NA     0

# using larger example data
set.seed(123)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  tms <- times[seq_len(round(runif(1, 1.3, 2)))]
  bnch <- sample(benchmarks, length(tms), replace = TRUE)
  data.frame(ids = i, time = tms, bench = bnch)
}))
# ... same steps as above
# this time no 0s because the data has more options present for start/end

          above benchmark intervene urgent watch
benchmark     3         1         2      1     4
intervene     7        NA         3      4     3
above         3         5        NA      2     2
urgent        5         5         7      3     3
watch         3         2        NA      2     2

